# How to deserialize JSON object in NET Core using Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject?

Tags: javascript, c#, json-deserialization

I create a WebSocket chat in NET Core. I don`t know how to deserialize real JSON object.

Parse this like a simple string - worked. But this is not what i need.

```
 let Message = `{
        login: userName,
        text: messageField.value
    }`
    chat.socket.send(Message);
    messageField.value = "";
```

JS Real code.

```
chat.sendMessage = function () {
    // var message = userName + ": " + messageField.value;
    let Message = {
        login: userName,
        text: messageField.value
    }
    chat.socket.send(Message);
    messageField.value = "";
}
```

And this is how i deserialize:

```
private static async Task<string> ReceiveStringAsync(WebSocket socket, CancellationToken ct = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        var buffer = new ArraySegment<byte>(new byte[8192]);
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            WebSocketReceiveResult result;
            do
            {
                ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

                result = await socket.ReceiveAsync(buffer, ct);
                ms.Write(buffer.Array, buffer.Offset, result.Count);
            }
            while (!result.EndOfMessage);

            ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            if (result.MessageType != WebSocketMessageType.Text)
            {
                return null;
            }

            // Encoding UTF8: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6455#section-5.6
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(ms, Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                JsonTextReader jsonReader = new JsonTextReader(reader);
                var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
                Message msg = serializer.Deserialize<Message>(jsonReader);
                return await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
```

returns simple object, 
not the one i tried to deserialize. 
In debugger its displayed as [object Object].

```
[JsonObject]
public class Message
{
    [JsonProperty("login")]
    public string login { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("text")]
    public string text { get; set; }
}
```

EXCEPTION

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'Metanit.Models.Message' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
>   To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.

Why exception tolds me Cannot deserialize the current JSON array
its not an array!
It is:
let Message = {
            login: userName,
            text: messageField.value
        }

[image]

Comment: What is te JSON input?

Comment: i dont know. its just a [object Object].

Comment: Debug your code when you `using (var reader = new StreamReader(ms, Encoding.UTF8))`. You can watch it like `reader.ReadToEnd()` and it returns the content in `String` format that you can read.

Comment: I added a pic. i think when i send Message object something goes wrong. something need to do in another way... here nothing to deserialize... i understand... =(

Comment: You're calling `ReadToEndAsync` twice - instead of doing that, just return the value you just read.

Comment: See also the [deserializing from a StreamReader](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeWithJsonSerializerFromFile.htm) docs.

Comment: If you using `reader.ReadToEndAsync();` you have to use like this: `reader.ReadToEndAsync().Result;` But instead I recommend just (for debugging) use `reader.ReadToEnd()`.

Comment: var value = reader.ReadToEndAsync(); it nothing. just to check

Comment: `var value = **await** reader.ReadToEndAsync()`

Comment: turanszkik  I FORGOT!! You right! I try this now!

Comment: @stuartd has the right answer, sorry my bad

Comment: no. its not the solution. whatever i tried result.Count = 15. It means [object Object]. Need to send message object another way. Need to learn JS.
/* Count prop of WebSocketReceiveResult result = 15 anyway

Comment: Have you tried to serialize this result to string? With Convert.ToString or just (String) before it?

Comment: its JS problem, man))) if send any object this way
chat.socket.send(Message);
    messageField.value = "";
WebSocketReceiveResult result = 15 anyway. Count prop of result

Comment: OK. Next question. How to serialize to BSON in JS. BSON.serialize(Message) - not worked...

Comment: WebSockets it very difficult thing... need to serialize object to binary then send it.